# Nested Objects in Realm

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

**Question:**

What is the correct way to use nested objects in realm?

**Task:**

I have a model called goals, e.g. "lose weight" and a model called "streaks" e.g. how often you checked in this week.

The idea is a user focuses on a goal for 1x 'Streak', at the end, they can start a new streak. Therefore, I'd like to have multiple streaks which all relate to one goal.

Here are the models I have so far:

**Streak Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Streak: Object {

    dynamic var owner: Goal!
    dynamic var StartDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var Day1 = ""
    dynamic var Day2 = ""
    dynamic var Day3 = ""
    dynamic var Day4 = ""
    dynamic var Day5 = ""
    dynamic var Day6 = ""
    dynamic var Day7 = ""
    dynamic var Completed = ""
    dynamic var Active = ""

// Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

//  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
//    return []
//  }
}
```

**Goal Model**

```
class Goal: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var Title = ""
    dynamic var Aim = ""
    dynamic var Action = ""
    dynamic var Active = 0
    let streaks = List<Streak>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String! {
        return "id"
    }

// Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

//  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
//    return []
//  }
}
```

As you can see, I've set the "owner" of a `streak` as `Goal!`. I've also created a Primary Key on `id` in the Goal, and also a list of `streaks` in the Goal model.

What I don't understand is how to store a `streak` correctly in the Realm.

To store a Goal, I have this:

```
let goalObj = Goal()
        goalObj.id = newID
        goalObj.Title = setGoal.text!
        goalObj.Aim = ""
        goalObj.Action = setHabit.text!
        goalObj.Active = 1
//      goalObj.streaks = [NSDate(),"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

        let realm = try! Realm()

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(goalObj)
```

I've commented the goalObj.streaks line as it's incorrect and gives an error (values are all dummy).

**My specific questions are:** 

1. How would I store a streak object which references a goal - where do i put the ID if at all.
2. how is best to update that streak. Should I create a streakID field as a primary key? I don't see a way to use a foreign key like in MySql.
3. is the List even necessary for this task?

Apologies for the beginner question. Appreciated, Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `goal` reference on your `Streak` class needs to be defined as:

dynamic var goal: Goal? // to-one relationships must be optional

Then you can just add a streak instance to Realm, and it will automatically link it to the correct goal.

Also, they don't recommend keeping both references in a to-many relationship (ie. parent-to-children and child-to-parent), because it is error-prone given Realm does not manage it for you. Consequently I just store the child-to-parent reference, and use `linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)` to dynamically retrieve the parent-to-children links. However, this has the disadvantage that you can't use the linkage in a predicate.

You don't specifically need a primary key for this to work. So if you have an array of streaks, you can just use:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(streaks)
}
```

Note that you have to add the parent (goal) to Realm before the children (streak).